# Async function in React triggers error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have an algorithm that can be used in a lot of places in my React app. For this reason, I need it to be asynchronous so as not to delay components' rendering.

Also, if there is an error in a reduce loop, I need to stop the function and return null. A try/catch format seems appropriate. However, React claims that:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The issue is not because of my algorithm, but because of its async nature. I have written this very simple example that triggers the exact same error:

```js
async function test(name){
    try{
      if(!name) {
        throw new Error
      }
      const formattedName = name.toUppercase()
      return formattedName
    }
    catch{
      return "error"
    }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
     {test("joe")}
    </>
  );
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Unless you `await` the async function it will return a promise object, never the value you `return`.

Comment: Even with  const formattedName = await name.toUppercase() the error remains.

Comment: Yes, await doesn't stop the function to keep returning a Promise

Comment: "*For this reason, I need it to be asynchronous so as not to delay components' rendering.*" - no, that's not how it works. Your algorithm is not asynchronous, and it should not be marked as `async`. And currently, your component cannot handle rendering without the result from the algorithm - that's what you'll need to actually fix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your use case but probably you just want to have a State in React that holds the name or whatever value you want and then render that value if it's available, something like:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")

async function test(name){
    try{
      if(!name) {
        throw new Error
      }
      const formattedName = name.toUppercase()
      setName(formattedName)
    }
    catch{
      return "error"
    }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
     {name}
    </>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Suppose that you have that `js` function in a `utils` folder or whatever that do all that parsing you mentioned. You can think this as an async call to an API, what you need to then is in your React component (suppose in the first render), the following:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(...)

useEffect(async () => {
  const data = await callToYourParsingFunctionThatIsAsync();
  setData(data);
}, [])
```

And then you render whatever you need from that `data` variable

Comment: No it's a translation function outside of React's scope. It checks a huge json file and return the right dynamic translation. So I can't use any state.

Comment: So what's the problem? You could keep setting the state. Editting my response right now

Comment: The problem is that if I have 600 calls of this function in my app, I'll need so many states. This is not a clean architecture.

Comment: I dont quite understand your use case but hou could have an HOC (High Order Component) or a Context Provider that will keep only one state and you can share the translation function to whoever needs it. But the answer is that. Please mark as correct answer if suitable

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  async function test(innerName) {
    if (innerName === name) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      if (!innerName) {
        throw new Error();
      }
      const formattedName = innerName;
      setName(formattedName);
    } catch {
      return "error";
    }
  }

  test("Joe");

  return <>{"Testing : " + name}</>;
}
```

You need to use the state for updating the render at a future event in time. A sample code looks like the above.

Comment: But if I have 600 calls of this function in my app, I'll need so many states... I think I need to find another way to handle errors inside the reduce.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 WTH is that function doing? Why do you think it is costly but still call it 600 times?

Comment: it's a translation function that checks a huge json file and return the right dynamic string based on the provided key and params. I can't add a state each time I use it, it's crazy.